# Error Messages Problem

Tags: help, blocked-services

I keep getting these error messages.  Generic Sock Error, Access Denied, and most recently, Access Denied-this website is using a security service to protect from online attacks whenever I try to access a particular website on the Tor Network.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Tor on the regular internet, the website does not see you. It sees the exit node that you are coming through. Exit nodes are not private. Once a company realizes that too many people "look like" an exit node, they start blocking people who come from there. Sometimes you might get lucky and visit that site from an exit node that they are not aware of and you can get in but that usually doesn't happen often.

Google is the number 1 offender when if comes to this, they will give you endless captchas so you are effectively banned while using Tor.

There is no workaround and hack to get by this if the company/website wants to ban Tor users.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of poor website's web server and/or CDN configuration. Some CDN's do have an option to deny Tor exit node IP's(the IP the website can see as a request source) - the same settings can be enabled in WAF like mod_security. That's **how** it happens - so you can not change this by an action from your side if you're using Tor as an exit to the website.

IMHO this is lame: in my experience running the servers - the Wild-Wild Web from a Clearnet side is actually far more dangerous than *any* of the darknets because of the requests per second rate is a magnitude higher than via darknet because of far less encryption involved and there is a way straighter route for the packets. Darknet ban because of "security risk" is not an excuse for sure.

As it should be - it's just as simple as it gets: every darknet provides the reverse tunnel or reverse proxy functionality, so - yes, you should just use it to have a darknet addresses for your service. Take a look at Facebook, for example - they have an official onion address with the HTTPS with a green certificate check at https://facebookcorewwwi.onion